# Why is my table view updating so slowly? Is this normal?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I created an app that stores some playlists in Core Data. I use a table view controller to display the playlists. Users can also add and delete playlists in the table view.

The delete button works fine. I added an add button to the right side of the navigation bar. When the button is pressed, an alert shows up and asks the user for the name of the playlist. If the user enters nothing, an error will be shown by another alert. If the user input is valid, the playlist will be added to the table view.

Here is the relevant code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class PlaylistController: UITableViewController {
    var playlists: [Playlists] = []
    let dataContext: NSManagedObjectContext! = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        if dataContext != nil {
            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Playlist", inManagedObjectContext: dataContext)
            let request = NSFetchRequest()
            request.entity = entity
            let playlists = try? dataContext.executeFetchRequest(request)
            if playlists != nil {
                for item in playlists! {
                    self.playlists.append(item as! Playlists)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //This will be called when the user clicks the add button
    @IBAction func addPlaylist(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "新播放列表", message: "请输入播放列表的名字", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({ (textField) -> Void in
            textField.placeholder = "名字"
        })
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "确定", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            if alert.textFields?.first?.text == "" || alert.textFields?.first?.text == nil {
                let failAlert = UIAlertController(title: "失败", message: "播放列表名不能为空", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                failAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "确定", style: .Default, handler: nil))
                self.presentViewController(failAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                return
            }
            let newPlaylist = Playlists(entity: NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Playlist", inManagedObjectContext: self.dataContext)!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.dataContext)
            newPlaylist.name = alert.textFields?.first?.text
            self.playlists.append(newPlaylist)
            do {
                try self.dataContext.save()
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "取消", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

When I click on the add button and give the playlist a name, and click OK (确定), I need to wait about 0.5 ~ 1 second to see the new cell show up.

What is causing this? My first guess is that the creation of the alerts took too long. But actually the alerts shows up very quickly! I think there must be something to do with the `reloadData` method. But what exactly? Is this normal behaviour of table views?

Comment: Most likely `save` takes too much time? Also it really depends on what you do in your table view delegates.

Comment: @Sulthan I did nothing in my delegate. I was just writing the data source part. I want to write the delegate part later.

Comment: You have a debugger. Debug! Use Instruments to find out what is happening during the delay.

Comment: Also use logging to make sure you don't have a threading issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like you are not using NSFetchedResultController. I guess your table data based on playlists. Maybe you can try to update table view first then save core data later.

```
self.playlists.append(newPlaylist)
self.tableView.reloadData()

self.dataContext.performBlock({ () -> Void in 
    do {
        try self.dataContext.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
})
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't seem to work for me. Still very slow, about the same speed

Comment: @Sweeper How about have save() in performBlock. Please check revised answer.

Comment: Perhaps you could actually recommend using a fetched results controller and expand on the benefits. Encourage proper code practices and core data usage instead of supporting a poor solution

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps doing a full reload of the tableview takes a long time (given that the data seems to come from NSManagedObjects).

Did you try to use insertRowsAtIndexPaths instead of self.tableView.reloadData() ?

Since you've already added the record to your array and you know at which row it should appear, it should not be necessary to reload the entire tableview.